# Checking If User has Modified Facebook Permission For App

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I am using `Facebook` to create a new user or log in to **Parse**.

1. User logs in to app using Facebook login
2. User is prompt to accept the permissions.
3. User accept all permissions that the app requested.

**4. User removed permission for app (delete app from Facebook)**

I am wondering what is the way for us to check if the user has change the authorization status of the app in Facebook.

How do I check it? How do we know that it is no longer connected?

`FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken();` does not do the job, as it can only check if the token exists or not in the device.

I.E.: The user goes to Facebook App settings and deleted the App from the list.

p.s.: Please help vote up this question as It's really hard to find the solution. Thank you!!

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Handling an Invalidated Session**
>
> We cannot know if the cached Facebook session is valid until we
> attempt to make a request to the API. A session can become invalidated
> if a user changes their password or revokes the application's
> privileges. When this happens, the user needs to be logged out. We can
> identify an invalid session error within a FBSDKGraphRequest
> completion handler and automatically log the user out.

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // handle successful response
        } else if ([[error userInfo][@"error"][@"type"] isEqualToString: @"OAuthException"]) { // Since the request failed, we can check if it was due to an invalid session
            NSLog(@"The facebook session was invalidated");
            [PFFacebookUtils unlinkUserInBackground:[PFUser currentUser]];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Some other error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
```

Source: [Integrate Login with Facebook](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/wiki/Integrate-Login-with-Facebook)

Comment: Would you happen to know the updated code for swift3?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the answer you're looking for in here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions

You could either:

1) Check for errors yourself:

```
let token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
if token.hasGranted("publish_actions") //Or whatever other permission you're checking
```

2) Perform some action anyway and check the error:

```
if error.userInfo[FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode] == 200
{
    //Handle missing permissions here
}
```

I'm guessing that the `currentAccessToken` would be cached information from the last time they logged in, so the second option might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure a *Deauthorize Callback URL* for your app. Therefore, you'll need to create a backend service which can handle the incoming HTTP POST requests from Facebook once a user deauthorizes your app.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.4#deauth-callback

for details.